# Cloud Build fails with resource location constraint

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have a policy in place which restricts resources to EU regions.

When I try to execute a cloud build, gcloud wants to create a bucket (gs://[PROJECT_ID]_cloudbuild) to store staging sources. This step fails, because the default bucket location ('us') is used:

```
"code": 412,
"message": "'us' violates constraint ‘constraints/gcp.resourceLocations’"
```

As a workaround I tried to pass an existing bucket located in a valid region (using --gcs-source-staging-dir), but I got the same error.

How can this be solved?

Here the HTTP logs:

```
$ gcloud --log-http builds submit --gcs-source-staging-dir gs://my-custom-bucket/staging \
--tag gcr.io/xxxxxxxxxx/quickstart-image .
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=xxxxxxxxxx&alt=json
method: POST
== headers start ==
accept: application/json
content-type: application/json
== headers end ==
== body start ==
{"name": "my-custom-bucket"}
== body end ==
==== request end ====
---- response start ----
-- headers start --
server: UploadServer
status: 412
-- headers end --
-- body start --
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "conditionNotMet",
    "message": "'us' violates constraint ‘constraints/gcp.resourceLocations’",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "If-Match"
   }
  ],
  "code": 412,
  "message": "'us' violates constraint ‘constraints/gcp.resourceLocations’"
 }
}

-- body end --
---- response end ----
----------------------
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 412: 'us' violates constraint ‘constraints/gcp.resourceLocations’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue investigated by Google Support. They came up with the following answer:

> After investigating with the different teams involved in this issue,
>   it seems like the restrictions affecting Cloud Build (in this case,
>   preventing resource allocation in US) is intended. The only workaround
>   that came up from the investigation was the creation of a new project
>   without the restrictions in place that allows the use of Cloud Build.

They also referred to a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63480105) (already mentioned by in @Christopher P 's comment - thanks for that)

Answer (score 20):

I found the solution to this problem. After you create the project (with resource location restriction enabled), you should create a new bucket with the name `[PROJECT_ID]_cloudbuild` in the preferred location.

When you don't do this, cloud build submit will automatically create a bucket in the US, this is not configurable. And because of the resource restrictions, cloud build is not able to create this bucket in the US and this fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 412: 'us' violates constraint 'constraints/gcp.resourceLocations'
```

When you create the bucket (by hand) with the same name, cloudbuild will take that bucket as default bucket. The solution was not immediately visible, because for projects that already had the cloudbuild bucket in place when the resource restrictions were applied, the problem did not appear.

Comment: I have the same exact problem, but creating the bucket did not fix it for me.
I still got the same error :(

Comment: Did you delete the default bucket and create a new one with the exact same name in the region allowed by your project? I have done this for all our 50 projects and it works like a charm.

Comment: This is pure madness. Thank you very much for sharing the fix. I would have never imagined that something that trivial would be left by google as is.

Comment: @Tobbey I agree, they should at least throw an error that points you in the right direction. Because it is not the actual run that fails, it is a precondition that is not met. This is probably due to the fact that cloud build was first available in the US. Not an excuse though, because companies usually want all their data (including build artifacts) stored within a certain region because of legislation.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Build will use a [default bucket to store logs](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#logsbucket). You can try to add `logsBucket` field to the build config file with a specific bucket like in the snippet:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  args: ['install', '.']
logsBucket: 'gs://mybucket'
```

You can find detailed information about the build configuration file [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config)

Comment: The problem is not the logs dir but the staging dir.

Comment: Sorry Black, I misunderstood your question at a first glance. Since you are using "Resource Location Restriction", the way to go is --gcs-source-staging-dir as you  have done. Did you check if the user/service account gcloud is logged in has write access to the custom bucket location?

Comment: Permissions are fine. As you can see in the logs the API for bucket creation is called without location property (which defaults to 'us' location as per API documentation: [https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/insert](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/insert) ).

Comment: Maybe is worth to change the location of the Container Registry where the image is hosted. 'gcr.io' hosts the images in the United States. You can tag your image with 'eu.gcr.io' host name for example. In [this](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) documentation you can find more options.

Comment: This was one of the things I tried, without success.

Comment: There is an open feature request to allow you to select the region where the build takes place. You can follow this in the [issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/63480105)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with location constraints , follow the below steps to fix it

1. After logging to gcp console, select the required project where you are facing the issue
2. Then choose "Organization policies" from the IAM console. Make sure you have the necessary permissions for it to get listed
3. Look for the policy "Google Cloud Platform - Resource Location Restriction" policy in the list. Typically it comes under the category of custom policy

   Please refer the this screenshot:
   [location constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrUnx.png)
4. Click on the policy, click on edit, drag down in custom values add the location which you want.

   using prefix in means it includes everything to mention specific value use location name with out prefix

   here " 'us' violates constraint ‘constraints/gcp.resourceLocations"
5. Enter value us in the custom value add it and save , if it requires all zone in us-east mention prefix in like this

   ```
   in:us-east4-locations
   ```

hope this works

[allowed values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maxFe.png)

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked fine when i shifted my registry from default gcr.io to eu.gcr.io