# gcloud beta run deploy --source . throws 412

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Due to corporate restrictions, I'm supposed to host everything on GCP in Europe. The organisation I work for, has set a restriction policy to enforce this.

When I deploy a cloud run instance from source with `gcloud beta run deploy --source . --region europe-west1` it seems the command tries to store the temporary files in a storage bucket in the `us`, which is not allowed. The command then throws a 412 error.

```
➜ gcloud beta run deploy cloudrun-service-name --source . --platform managed --region=europe-west1 --allow-unauthenticated
This command is equivalent to running `gcloud builds submit --tag [IMAGE] .` and `gcloud run deploy cloudrun-service-name --image [IMAGE]`

Building using Dockerfile and deploying container to Cloud Run service [cloudrun-service-name] in project [PROJECT_ID] region [europe-west1]
X Building and deploying new service... Uploading sources.                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  - Uploading sources...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  . Building Container...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  . Creating Revision...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  . Routing traffic...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  . Setting IAM Policy...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Deployment failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) HTTPError 412: 'us' violates constraint 'constraints/gcp.resourceLocations'
```

I see the Artifact Registry Repository being created in the correct region, but not the storage bucket.

To bypass this I have to create a storage bucket first in the correct region with the name `PROJECT_ID_cloudbuild`. Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud Build fails with resource location constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53206667/cloud-build-fails-with-resource-location-constraint)

Comment: @maercky I posted an answer below. Please go through the solution, try it and see if you face any issues. Revert back with feedback.

Comment: Hi @PriyashreeBhadra, thanks for your reply. There are apparently other workarounds, as you illustrate (and for which - thank you!), but not a built-in "clean" solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message indicates that the bucket is forced to be created in the US regardless of the Organisation policy set in Europe. As per this [public issue tracker comment](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/63480105#comment11),

> “Cloud build submit creates a [PROJECT_ID]_cloudbuild bucket in the
> US. This will of course not work when resource restrictions apply.
> What you can do as a workaround is to create that bucket yourself in
> another location. You should do this before your first cloud build
> submit.”

This has been a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63480105) and I found two workarounds that can help you achieve what you want.

The first workaround is by using “gcloud builds submit” with additional flags:

- Create a new bucket with the name [PROJECT_ID]_cloudbuild in the
  preferred location.
- Specify non-buckets using [--gcs-source-staging-dir](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--gcs-source-staging-dir) and
  [--gcs-log-dir](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--gcs-log-dir) [2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63480105) ===> this flag is required as if it is not set
  it will create a bucket in the US.

The second workaround is by using a cloudbuild.yaml and the “--gcs-source-staging-dir” flag:

- Create a bucket in the region, dual-region or multi-region you may
  want
- Create a [cloudbuild.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#structure_of_a_build_config_file) for [storing a build artifacts](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/store-build-artifacts)
- You can find an example of the YAML file in the following [external
  documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982068/how-can-i-specify-a-region-for-the-cloud-storage-buckets-used-by-cloud-build-for), please note that I cannot vouch for its accuracy
  since it is not from GCP.
- Run the command :

> gcloud builds submit
> --gcs-source-staging-dir="gs://example-bucket/cloudbuild-custom" --config cloudbuild.yaml

Please try these workarounds and let me know if it worked for you.